Editing Imported JPG
I'm in Blender 3.6. Is it possible to edit an imported jpg natively? I see there is an add-on for sale called Image Editor Plus: https://blendermarket.com/products/image-editor-plus
What I'm mainly interested in being able to cut/slice/mask an image. I know that it can be done in other software and then imported but just wondering if workflow could be more streamlined.
Thanks so much for any advice/suggestions.

Concerning the addon, its product description says enough, no need to repeat it here. As for vanilla Blender, you xan definitely paint images, and do some form of procedural editing with the compositing nodes. But if you are looking for an actual image editing solution, a dedicated program would do the job better and quicker.

Got it! Thank you so much for your very helpful response. It's much appreciated!
